# How to CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ... WHERE another_field IS NULL in H2

Tags: sql, h2

I'm doing

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON car (license_plate) WHERE deleted IS NULL`

The use case is soft deletes:

1. We create a row for the car, with deleted set to null and the license_plate unique
2. Now we should not be allowed to enter another car with the same license plate
3. We soft delete the car by setting deleted to something
4. Now we should be allowed to enter a new car with the same license plate.

This works with postgres (running in a test container), but not with H2 or HSQLDB. Is there a way to achieve the same thing with H2, or any other in-memory database that I can create programmatically from Java?

Answer (score 0):

see: [PostgreSQL: Create an index to quickly distinguish NULL from non-NULL values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31966218/postgresql-create-an-index-to-quickly-distinguish-null-from-non-null-values)

```
CREATE TABLE public.car (
    id int4 NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    licenseplate varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    deleted timestamp NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX car_licenseplate_idx ON public.car USING btree (licenseplate) WHERE (deleted IS NULL);
```

I did create the field `deleted` as timestamp, so you could add a trigger to update deleted with `now()` when the record is 'soft' deleted.

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=fa01661ed19bdf2fe1facce46e94ba9a)

Comment: But Postgres already works, that's not the problem. The problem was doing the same for H2.

Comment: The same is possible in SQLite, I do not have H2 (and sorry about mis-reading your question)